# How to stop the sound/audio when you press the back button in the phone

Tags: java, android

how can i stop the audio from playing when i press the back button in my phone. when i go to another activity the audio is still playing unless i close the app. here's my code:

```
    FloatingActionButton fab7 = (FloatingActionButton) this.findViewById(R.id.fab7);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create( this, R.raw.cebu);
    fab7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View view) {;

            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
            } else {
                mp.start();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) declare `MediaPlayer mp;` outside `onCreate`

2.) `override onStop` and apply the same logic of click listener inside `onStop`

> why `onStop` not `onBackPress`?

### Because you want to pause the player when you go outside app **as well as when you go to another activity**

```
MediaPlayer mp;
onCreate(..){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create( this, R.raw.cebu);
    fab7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {;
            pausePlayer();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop()
    pausePlayer();
}

void pausePlayer(){
    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
    } else {
        mp.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPress() {
     pausePlayer();
     mp.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override [Activity#onBackPress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method to stop your player when pressing Back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPress() {
     if (mp != null) {
         mp.stop();
         mp.release();
         mp = null;
     }
}
```

If you want to stop your player when your Activity finish, and **don't care why** (may be Back press, another Activity started, app crashed,..), you can override [Activity#onStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()) so you will **make sure** your music is immediately stop whenever your Activity gone!

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (mp != null) {
         mp.stop();
         mp.release();
         mp = null;
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Btw, note that you should use `mp.stop()` instead of `mp.pause()` then `mp.release()` to avoid memory/resources leak!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to detect and pause the Mediaplayer

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Back button pressed Song paused");
    mp.pause();


}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write mediaplayer.stop();
on start of back activity when u gone